# Storing Variable in C

Tags: c, variables, types, char, int

I am having some challenges with a basic concept in C. Help would be much obliged.
I went ahead and annotated the code with the explanation of the code as well the question I am trying to ask there as well.

```
void main (void)
{
  printf("%x", (unsigned)((char) (0x0FF))); //I want to store just 0xFF;
  /* Purpose of the next if-statement is to check if the unsigned char which is 255
   * be the same as the unsigned int which is also 255. How come the console doesn't print
   * out "sup"? Ideally it is supposed to print "sup" since 0xFF==0x000000FF.
   */
  if(((unsigned)(char) (0x0FF))==((int)(0x000000FF))) 
     printf("%s","sup");
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Basic concept #1: main() should return int.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion in the question here. You have no variables.

Comment: @stefan: `unsigned == unsigned int`

Comment: Since there are no variables in this code and nothing is being stored, then yes, you are having problems with truly basic concepts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have gotten your parentheses wrong,

```
if(((unsigned)(char) (0x0FF))==((int)(0x000000FF)))
```

performs two casts on the left operand, first to `char`, usually<sup>(1)</sup> resulting in -1, and then that value is cast to `unsigned int`, usually<sup>(2)</sup> resulting in 2^32-1 = 4294967295.

<sup>(1)</sup> If `char` is signed, eight bits wide, two's complement is used and the conversion is done by just taking the least significant byte, as is the case for the majority of hosted implementations. If `char` is unsigned, or wider than eight bits, the result will be 255.

<sup>(2)</sup> If the cast to `char` resulted in -1 and `unsigned int` is 32 bits wide.

Comment: "Correct" version: `(unsigned char)0xFF`

Comment: Why does (char) 0x0FF equal -1?

Comment: @1'' _usually_. 0xFF is the eight-bit two's complement representation of `-1`, and on most machines a cast to a smaller integer type is just truncation of the bit-pattern with the appropriate reinterpretation. But conversions of out-of-range values to signed integer types is implementation-defined, so the result could be something different (on sign-and-magnitude machines, -127 is a likely candidate, on ones' complement machines -0).

Comment: 'usually resulting in -1" -- More accurately and precisely, it results in -1 if char is signed in the implementation. There are implementations in which char is unsigned, and if one spends most of one's time with such an implementation, then `(char)0xFF` "usually" will not be equal to -1.

Comment: 'You have gotten your parentheses wrong' -- There are also way more of them than necessary, and they don't aid readability. `if( (unsigned char)0x0FF == (int)0x000000FF )` will do (and the `(int)` cast is also not necessary, and isn't a good idea since it mixes signed and unsigned and will get a warning from some implementations).

Comment: @DanielFischer I of course knew what you meant when I pointed out its imprecision. Also, since saying "I'm willing to bet" on the internet comes cheaply (as in, it never actually happens), that carries no more weight than "I think". But anyway, +1 for the added precision in your edit; thank you.

Comment: I'd rather think it corresponds more to "I'm pretty sure", which is a bit stronger than I think. Although that is a bet I'd be willing to make IRL, who'd be the other part, so yes, it comes cheaply.